# How can I write my redirect so it does not show the directory?

Tags: .htaccess

If I'm visiting my website for the first time then it always displays the directory that I'm pointing my site to. For example, if I visit example.com, it redirects to example.com/site.2014/. If I remove the directory from the URL, and revisit, it doesn't show up anymore. Can anyone explain why this happens? I have the following information in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site.2014/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site.2014/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site.2014/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site.2014/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site.2014/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser.